# Problems with Password setting with HTMLUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, authentication, passwords, htmlunit

This is my Class that should login to a website by setting a specific username and password in their fields.
Running it, it works until it sets the Username but it seems to have problem with finding/filling the password box.
I double-checked it the HTML to be sure that I put the correct password-box's name but still not working.
Thanks for help

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;

public class FormSubmit {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        submittingForm();
    }

    public static void submittingForm() {

        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);



        try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {

            webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
            webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("website");

            final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("formname");

            final HtmlSubmitInput loginButton = form.getInputByName("inputname");
            final HtmlTextInput username = form.getInputByName("name");

            username.setValueAttribute("namevalue");         
            System.out.println(username);

            final HtmlTextInput password = form.getInputByName("password");
            password.removeAttribute("disabled");
            password.setValueAttribute("passvalue");
            System.out.println(password);

            final HtmlPage page2 =  (HtmlPage) form.getInputByValue(" Login ").click();
            System.out.println(page2.getBody());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the website, what is the username/password, so others can reproduce the issue?

Comment: This is the website: https://applicazioni.gse.it/GWA_UI/
But I prefer to not give username and password. If you can find a way print at screen the value of fake username and password once you assigned it that would probably solve the problem since I don't have problem with Login but with assigning password a value.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use an old HmltUnit version from the API usage, please update yours (preferably to the [latest build](https://ci.canoo.com/teamcity/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=HtmlUnit_FastBuild&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts)).

The far below code works:

Please note:

1. Cookies and JavaScripts are enabled by default, you don't need to set them to `true`
2. `password` input should be `HtmlPasswordInput`, otherwise you get `ClassCastException`

```
public class FormSubmit {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
            final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://applicazioni.gse.it/GWA_UI/");

            System.out.println(page1.asXml());
            final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("aspnetForm");

            final HtmlTextInput username = form.getInputByName("ctl00$ctl00$cphFormAppl$cphRisultatiRicerca$txtUserid");

            username.setValueAttribute("namevalue");         

            final HtmlPasswordInput password = form.getInputByName("ctl00$ctl00$cphFormAppl$cphRisultatiRicerca$txtPassword");
            password.setValueAttribute("passvalue");

            final HtmlPage page2 = (HtmlPage) form.getInputByValue(" Login ").click();
            System.out.println(page2.asText());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, could you also upvote the answer, if it is useful?

Comment: I think I don't have enough reputation for that :(